# MVC: why controller is the strategy for the view

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, strategy-pattern, design-principles

Here is definition of `Strategy Pattern`:

> Strategy - defines a family of algorithms, encapsulates each one, and
>   makes them interchangeable. Strategy lets the algorithm vary
>   independently from clients that use it.

So, Strategy separate a functionality into two parts: one which doesn't change,  and another which can change at some future time.

And, in MVC, they say that:

> the controller is the strategy for the view

It means controller is vary and View might not change in the future.

I don't understand so much,yet. I think both of them can change in the future.

Please explain for me why people say that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect you may have seen the note "the controller is the strategy for the view" in the C3 wiki section on [Model View Controller As An Aggregate Design Pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ModelViewControllerAsAnAggregateDesignPattern), which is interesting, but a bit terse.

The idea is described a bit more completely in the introduction of [Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612), where the section on MVC says:

> MVC also lets you change the way a view responds to user input without changing its visual presentation. You might want to change the way it responds to the keyboard, for example, or have it use a pop-up menu instead of command keys. MVC encapsulates the response mechanism in a Controller object. There is a class hierarchy of controllers, making it easy to create a new controller as a variation on an existing one.
>
> A view uses an instance of a Controller subclass to implement a particular response strategy; to implement a different strategy, simply replace the instance with a different kind of controller. It's even possible to change a view's controller at run-time to let the view change the way it responds to user input. For example, a view can be disabled so that it doesn't accept input simply by giving it a controller that ignores input events.
>
> The View-Controller relationship is an example of the Strategy design pattern. A Strategy is an object that represents an algorithm. It's useful when you want to replace the algorithm either statically or dynamically, when you have a lot of variants of the algorithm, or when the algorithm has complex data structures that you want to encapsulate.

Summarizing this a bit, you can use the same view with different controllers to have different behavior in different parts of your system, you can replace the controller at run-time to enable or disable particular functions, and the controller encapsulates the complex interactions of updating the model.